# TinyMCE reload editor

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce, tinymce-4

I have simple modal window with textarea:

```
<div class="box-modal" id="product_modal">
    <div class="box-modal_close arcticmodal-close"><img id="closePopupImage" src="/images/icons/popup_icon_close.png"></div>
    <div id="product_fields">
        <span class="product_label">{'TEXT_PRODUCT_NAME'|tr}:</span>
        <input type="text" class="product_name">
        <span>{'TEXT_PRODUCT_PRICE'|tr}:</span>
        <input type="text" class="product_price">
        <span>{'TEXT_PRODUCT_AMOUNT'|tr}:</span>
        <input type="text" class="product_amount">
        <br>
        <span class="product_label pr_comment">{'TEXT_PRODUCT_COMMENT'|tr}:</span>
        <textarea id="product_comment" class="product_comment"></textarea>
        <img class="add_one_more" src="/images/icons/add_button.png" title="{'TEXT_ADD_ONE_MORE'|tr}">
    </div>
</div>
```

I have table with button with class .add_products_btn.

My js:

```
 function makeTinyMceEditor() {
            tinymce.init({
                selector: "#product_comment",
                plugins: "link"
            });
    }

$(".add_products_btn").click(function () {
        $("#product_modal").arcticmodal();
        makeTinyMceEditor();
    });
```

So when I click in button in first time my tinymce works fine. But when I click on the second button my tinymce doesn't work (think because textarea's ids are the same every time when I click on the button).
How can I remove old id instanse from editor for use them again?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You need to use the `remove()` API to detach TinyMCE from the DOM ***before*** you close your Modal window. You can then use `init()` again when the modal is recreated.

https://www.tinymce.com/docs/api/tinymce/root_tinymce/#remove

Comment: New link for above https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/api/tinymce/root_tinymce/#remove